# R extract regression coefficients from multiply regression via lapply command

Tags: r, linear-regression, lapply

I have a large dataset with several variables, one of which is a state variable, coded 1-50 for each state.  I'd like to run a regression of 28 variables on the remaining 27 variables of the dataset (there are 55 variables total), and specific for each state.

In other words, run a regression of variable1 on covariate1, covariate2, ..., covariate27 for observations where state==1.  I'd then like to repeat this for variable1 for states 2-50, and the repeat the whole process for variable2, variable3,..., variable28.

I think I've written the correct R code to do this, but the next thing I'd like to do is extract the coefficients, ideally into a coefficient matrix.  Could someone please help me with this?  Here's the code I've written so far:

```
for (num in 1:50) {

    #PUF is the data set I'm using

    #Subset the data by states
    PUFnum <- subset(PUF, state==num)

    #Attach data set with state specific data
    attach(PUFnum)

    #Run our prediction regression
    #the variables class1 through e19700 are the 27 covariates I want to use
    regression <- lapply(PUFnum,  function(z) lm(z ~ class1+class2+class3+class4+class5+class6+class7+
                                                     xtot+e00200+e00300+e00600+e00900+e01000+p04470+e04800+
                                                     e09600+e07180+e07220+e07260+e06500+e10300+
                                                     e59720+e11900+e18425+e18450+e18500+e19700))

    Beta <- lapply(regression, function(d) d<- coef(regression$d))


    detach(PUFnum)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is another example of the classic `Split-Apply-Combine` problem, which can be addressed using the `plyr` package by @hadley. In your problem, you want to

1. Split data frame by state
2. Apply regressions for each subset
3. Combine coefficients into data frame.

I will illustrate it with the `Cars93` dataset available in `MASS` library. We are interested in figuring out the relationship between `horsepower` and `enginesize` based on `origin` of country.

```
# LOAD LIBRARIES
require(MASS); require(plyr)

# SPLIT-APPLY-COMBINE
regressions <- dlply(Cars93, .(Origin), lm, formula = Horsepower ~ EngineSize)
coefs <- ldply(regressions, coef)

   Origin (Intercept) EngineSize
1     USA    33.13666   37.29919
2 non-USA    15.68747   55.39211
```

EDIT. For your example, substitute `PUF` for `Cars93`, `state` for `Origin` and `fm` for the formula

Answer (score 1):

I've cleaned up your code slightly:

```
fm <- z ~ class1+class2+class3+class4+class5+class6+class7+
          xtot+e00200+e00300+e00600+e00900+e01000+p04470+e04800+
          e09600+e07180+e07220+e07260+e06500+e10300+
          e59720+e11900+e18425+e18450+e18500+e19700

PUFsplit <- split(PUF, PUF$state)
mod <- lapply(PUFsplit, function(z) lm(fm, data=z))

Beta <- sapply(mod, coef)
```

If you wanted, you could even put this all in one line:

```
Beta <- sapply(lapply(split(PUF, PUF$state), function(z) lm(fm, data=z)), coef)
```