# Extract Group Regression Coefficients in R w/ PLYR

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to run a regression for every zipcode in my dataset and save the coefficients to a data frame but I'm having trouble.

Whenever I run the code below, I get a data frame called "coefficients" containing every zip code but with the intercept and coefficient for every zipcode being equal to the results of the simple regression `lm(Sealed$hhincome ~ Sealed$square_footage)`.

When I run the code as indicated in Ranmath's example at the link below, everything works as expected. I'm new to R after many years with STATA, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[R extract regression coefficients from multiply regression via lapply command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014308/r-extract-regression-coefficients-from-multiply-regression-via-lapply-command)

```
library(plyr)
Sealed <- read.csv("~/Desktop/SEALED.csv")

x <- function(df) {
      lm(Sealed$hhincome ~ Sealed$square_footage)
}

regressions <- dlply(Sealed, .(Sealed$zipcode), x)
coefficients <- ldply(regressions, coef)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `dlply` takes a `...` argument that allows additional arguments to be passed to the function, you can make things even simpler:

```
dlply(Sealed,.(zipcode),lm,formula=hhincome~square_footage)
```

The first two arguments to `lm` are `formula` and `data`.  Since `formula` is specified here, `lm` will pick up the next argument it is given (the relevant zipcode-specific chunk of `Sealed`) as the `data` argument ...

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the function:

```
x <- function(df) {
      lm(Sealed$hhincome ~ Sealed$square_footage)
}
```

to each subset of your data, so we shouldn't be surprised that the output each time is exactly

```
lm(Sealed$hhincome ~ Sealed$square_footage)
```

right? Try replacing `Sealed` with `df` inside your function. That way you're referring to the variables in each individual piece passed to the function, not the whole variable in the data frame `Sealed`.

Comment: Thanks Joran, that was really helpful! It should definitely help me out with other R functions as well

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `plyr` but rather in the definition of the function.   You are calling a function, but not doing anything with the variable.

As an analogy,

```
 myFun <- function(x) {
    3 * 7
  }

    >  myFun(2)
    [1] 21
    >  myFun(578)
    [1] 21
```

If you run this function on different values of x, it will still give you 21, no matter what x is. That is, there is no reference to x within the function.  In my silly example, the correction is obvious;  in your function above, the confusion is understandable. The `$hhincome` and `$square_footage` should conceivably serve as variables.

But you want your x to vary over what comes ***before*** the `$`.   As @Joran correctly pointed out,  swap `sealed$hhincome` with `df$hhincome` (and same for `$squ..`) and that will help.

Comment: Very illustrative example Ricardo, made the issue much more clear to me; my function was abstracted from the relevant variable listed in the first line. Thanks!